# If I downgrade gwibber, will it still work with twitter?

Tags: gwibber

I am considering returning gwibber to the version from the standard repo (as opposed to the unstable ppa) so I can use the me-menu again. However, I use twitter quite a bit, and I'd hate to be hit with OAuth problems. Will this be safe?

Comment: I would be interested in figuring out why the Me Menu in maverick doesn't work with gwibber from the unstable PPA.  I am a Gwibber developer and the maintainer of the Me Menu, and as far as I know that combination should work, but I haven't tested that lately.  Please give me some details of the symptoms you are seeing.

Comment: @Ken VanDine When I try to send a post, the text in the input box does not disappear on its own, and if I replace it, it still is not sent when I press enter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version are you downgrading to?

I believe `maverick-updates` has a backported OAuth fix. Either way, it's had several version bumps since `maverick`-proper.

If it's before Maverick, again it may have been backported in the updates repo but I can't say for certain.

Comment: I was referring to what ever comes with maverick (as you mentioned - maverick-updates - should be what I mean).